# FMT conversion on xmltex

Tags: xmltex

I have a base xml-tex setup file like `.xmt, .cfg, .tex`, customized `.sty` files and `cls`.

I will try to convert the `fmt` file by using the below command.

```
latex -ini -jobname="fmt-file-name" "&latex" mylatexformat.ltx """filename*.*"""
```

But the `XMLTeX` commands are not supported for `FMT` file creation . For Example `\XMLelments, \UnicodeCharacter` is not supported. The undefined control sequence error is thrown.

I would like to protect xmltex set-up source files like "sample.cfg, sample-entity.sty, sample.xmt files except `sample.tex` and `sample.xml`. So, i would like to convert those files into `FMT` format similar to `exe` format.

I hope that the source file is converted into FMT file format that format is useful to avoid any unknown person editing those files. But, i can't convert those files.

I have provided my MWE below.

```
%%Sample.tex%%
\def\xmlfile{sample.xml}
\input xmltex

%%Sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd">
<article>
<front>
<article-meta>
<title-group>
<article-title>The sample title</article-title>
</title-group>
</article-meta>
</front>
<body>
<sec id="j_nanoph-2018-0214_s_001">
<title>Introduction</title>
<p>The <bold>Sample.cfg, Sample.xmt, Sample-entity.sty</bold> files needs to be converted into unreadable format &#x00C1; &#x00E1;.</p>
</body>
</article>

%%Sample.xmt%%

\XMLentity{TeX}{\TeX}
\XMLentity{LaTeX}{\LaTeX}

%%%%Main Root Tag%%%%
\XMLelement{article}%
    {}%
    {\documentclass{article}%
    \begin{document}}%
    {\end{document}}%
%%%%

\XMLelement{bold}{}{\xmlgrab}{\textbf{#1}}


%%%%Front Matter Tags%%%%
\XMLelement{front}{}{}{%
  \date{}
  \maketitle%
}%
%%%%

\XMLelement{article-title}{}{\xmlgrab}{\title{#1}}

\XMLelement{title}{}{\xmlgrab}{\section*{#1}}

\XMLelement{p}{}{}{\par}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Output:

[image: MWE Output]
So, could you please advice how to convert those files in `FMT` file format.

Comment: your example isn't very clear but you have started from the latex format and don't appear to have input any xmltex command definitions, did you intend to start from the xmltex format?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited my questions and also provide mwe for your reference. It's possible to Change fmt file