# How to convert the xmltex supporting files to binary file format like (FMT) conversion on LaTeX

Tags: xmltex

I will try to convert the xmltex supporting files like `(xmltex.tex, xmltex.xmt, xmltex.cfg, .sty, .cls)` to binary file format like (.fmt) format conversion.

I already posted my question with `MWE` for the following link: [Supporting files for MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488942/fmt-conversion-on-xmltex)

I use the following latex package options like `mylatexformat.sty'' and also try the below mentioned command lines:

```
latex -ini -jobname="filename" "&latex filename.cls\dump"

etex -initialize -save-size=20000 -stack-size=20000 -jobname="filename" "&latex" mylatexformat.ltx """filename.cls"""
```

But `(.xmt, xmltex.tex, .cfg)` files are not supporting this `(fmt)` file font conversions.

How to acheive the successful `FMT` transformation on xmltex support files. It's possible to convert those file format `(.xmt, .cfg, xmltex.tex)` to fmt format. Could you please anyone advice on this.

Comment: If you are using `xmltex` where does LaTeX come in? Simply `pdftex -ini xmltex.tex` dumps a format for me.

Comment: texlive includes xmltex formats by default, and associated commands so you can use `pdfxmltex myfile.xml` on the commandline directly, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: is this question any different to the previous one? (it is better to edit the original question to clarify to rather than add additional comments as a new question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't find out solution for this. So i request to explain the new question.

Comment: @JosephWright The following command like `pdftex -ini xmltex.tex` is dumps the xmltex very well. But how can i utilize the dumps file on tex document. I will try to give this command like `%&xmltex`. But the command line is not working for me.

Comment: `pdftex "&xmltex"`